# How to generate CPU Profile from isolate*.logs

Tags: node.js, profiling, v8, profiler

I'm trying to read `isolate*.log` that are generated when we run node process with `node --prof myApp.js`

I'm currently using `flamebearer` which is a good tool but I'll like to inspect the above logs in chrome devtools

I'm using this command for `flamebearer`

```
node --prof-process --preprocess -j isolate*.log | flamebearer
```

```
node --prof-process isolate*.log > report.txt
```

Also doesn't seem to be the item supported to be opened as CPU profile so what would be the best way to translate `isloate*.log` to `.cpuprofile` that chrome devtool can process.

Comment: Have you tried running it with `--cpu-prof` instead?